# How to catch IOException Error in eclispe for Android?

Tags: android

I want to catch an  IOException Error and want to show it in the form of toast for android application development. But when ever i apply catch(`IOexception` e), after try block it says to throws (throws `IOException`) with function name after which i am to catch error message.. Please Provide Some assistance....

Comment: It is quite unclear what you mean. Could you show your code, tell what "it" is, and what it exactly says.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

May be you desire to '**throws**' catched exception above the call stack, and next, catch and process all exception in one place (or '**layer**') of code?)

Comment: it got resolved... thankx for your attention people... function have to throw ioexception... so that the place where it is declared in trycatch block, catch block will catch ioexception in that fucntion....